# Regarding R-symmetry in SUSY algebra

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

In John Terning, Modern Supersymmetry, $R$-symmetry is introduced as below:
 "The SUSY algebra is invariant under a multiplication of the supercharges by a phase, so in general there is a linear combination of U(1) charges called $R$-charge, that doesn't commute with the supercharges."

He the proceeds to write down the following commutator relations: 
$$[Q_{\alpha}, R] = Q_{\alpha}, $$
$$[Q_{\alpha}^{\dagger}, R] = - Q_{\alpha}^{\dagger}$$

How are the above relations derived?

Comment: That's pretty much a convention: we say an operator $\mathcal O$ has charge $q$ under the $\mathrm U(1)$ symmetry generated by $T$ iff $[\mathcal O,T]=q\mathcal O$. In other words, this algebra *defines* what it means to be charged under a $\mathrm U(1)$ symmetry. See also [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305474/84967).

Comment: ^ what AFT said. If that's confusing, have a look at how time evolution acts on operators in Heisenberg picture -- it's by commutator. In general the finite action is by a conjugation, which infinitesimally becomes a commutator.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform your answer in the post was helpful, got it, thanks.

Comment: @knzhou i went through the post AFT linked, the example which you give now follows from the general case. Thanks.